# Display single event on a page with events planner wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

How do I display a single event with the events planner plugin in wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-planner/

If I use [events_planner event_id="1932"]  it displays all the events instead of displaying a single one

How do I display a single event ?

Has anybody used it ? Please help